# Get index of li with ID?

Tags: jquery

I have this sortable list:

```
            <ul id="sortable">
              <li id="Item1"><img src="../../../../IMAGES/04_01/P2_0401_18.jpg" /></li>
              <li id="Item2"><img src="../../../../IMAGES/04_01/P2_0401_20.jpg" /></li>
              <li id="Item3"><img src="../../../../IMAGES/04_01/P2_0401_22.jpg" /></li>
              <li id="Item4"><img src="../../../../IMAGES/04_01/P2_0401_24.jpg" /></li>
              <li id="Item5"><img src="../../../../IMAGES/04_01/P2_0401_26.jpg" /></li>
              <li id="Item6"><img src="../../../../IMAGES/04_01/P2_0401_28.jpg" /></li>
            </ul>
```

and of course, when the users move the items, the index of each item ID changes. What I'm trying to do is store the new indexes of the items in separate variables `itemIndex1, itemIndex2, etc` so I will be able to check their positions in a function that runs later on.

This is the code that's causing my conundrum:

```
var itemIndex1 = $('#sortable li').index($('#sortable li:nth-child(1)'));
var itemIndex2 = $('#sortable li').index($('#sortable li:nth-child(2)'));
var itemIndex3 = $('#sortable li').index($('#sortable li:nth-child(3)'));
var itemIndex4 = $('#sortable li').index($('#sortable li:nth-child(4)'));
var itemIndex5 = $('#sortable li').index($('#sortable li:nth-child(5)'));
var itemIndex6 = $('#sortable li').index($('#sortable li:nth-child(6)'));
```

I found this solution in another question here on stackoverflow, but it doesn't really suit my purposes because each `itemIndex` simply returns the index of each li child, regardless of its ID. `itemIndex1` will always return `0`, `itemIndex2` will always return `1`, etc.

I'd like to be able to get the index of `#Item4` for example, if the user has dragged it to the `0` index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [.index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) on it's own:

```
var idx = $("#Item4").index();
```

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is
>   an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
>   jQuery object relative to its sibling elements