# Get child's index

Tags: jquery

Has anyone got an idea how to get child's index in jQuery. E.g.:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li class="active">Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I want to get the li.active's child index ? Any ideas how?

Comment: What do you mean by key? It's index?

Comment: Excuse me, yes I mean index.

Comment: Alternatively, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23009441/get-index-of-li-with-id?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery's `index()` function](http://api.jquery.com/index/) for this:

```
$( "li.active" ).index();
```

> #### Return Values
>
> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean you want to get the index, you can use jQuery's [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function, which returns the index relative to the parent as a 0-based integer. For example:

```
$('li.active').index();
```

In your code will produce `1` (because `li.active` is the second element of the parent `<ul>`).

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/63j98/)

From the Doc:

> **Return Values**
>
> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is
>   an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
>   jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.index()`.

```
$('li.active').index();
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W33t3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul>li.active").index()
```

maybe what u want?